# Trying to convert a Component name from string to Component type in angular 9 gives Type passed in is not ComponentType error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Template HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="getComponent(item.component); injector: dynamicComponentInjector">
</ng-container>
```

In .ts file ( THIS WORKS)

```
getComponent(component){
    return component; //component = 'ProductTitleComponent'
}
```

But (THIS DOESN'T WORK) since I an getting the value from Database, I am getting it as string like this "ProductTitleComponent". I tried below option but nothing happen.

Getting ERROR: *Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not ComponentType, it does not have 'ɵcmp' property.*

```
getComponent(component){
  return component as Component; //component = 'ProductTitleComponent'
}


getComponent(component){
  return JSON.parse(component); //component = 'ProductTitleComponent'
}
```

Comment: You're not even trying to convert it, you're just passing the string which obviously cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by doing this

```
getComponent(component){
  const comp = { ProductTitleComponent }
  return comp[component];
}
```

Considering 'ProductTitleComponent' as component value. In this case I have to add a component each time I create one to *comp* object. Is there any better solution.